# Swft: Make a ball and position it at the bottom of the screen vertically. Then move the ball vertically when you press the ball in swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, user-controls, collision

Yo guys! Im new here on stack and im also a new programmer. I'm trying to teach myself swift but I"ve ran into some issues. Im trying to make a ball move vertically only when you press the ball, so if you press the screen and not the ball it will not go up. Here is what I have so far.

```
  //Function on vetical movement
func moveVertically (up:Bool) {
    let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 3, duration: 0.50)
    let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
    if up {
        player?.run(repeatAction)
    }else{
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -3, duration: 0.01)
        let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(moveAction)
        player?.run(repeatAction)
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
        let node = self.nodes(at: location).first

        if node?.name == "player"{
            moveVertically(up: true)
        }else {moveVertically(up: false)

    }

}
```

}

```
func createPlayer(){

        //create a ball
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint.zero,
                    radius: 15,
                    startAngle: 0,
                    endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2,
                    clockwise: true)
        let ball = SKShapeNode(path: path)
        ball.lineWidth = 1
        ball.fillColor = .blue
        ball.strokeColor = .white
        ball.glowWidth = 0.5
        //set the player to ball and manipulate the player position.
        player = ball
        player?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (scene?.size.height)! / -2.5)



        self.addChild(player!)
    }
```

P.S. I'm trying to get the ball to move vertically but also when you press the right side of the ball it goes to the left, and vice versa but when I say to the left I mean go vertically up and to the left.

Comment: try to use PanGestureRecognizer

Comment: Hi - so currently does the ball move at all when you press it? Also, when this is working and you press the ball, the ball will move up so your finger will no longer be on the ball. Should the ball stop moving then unless you move your finger or is it enough that your finger *was* on the ball when you started?

Comment: what is the actual problem here?

Comment: Sorry guys, yeah the ball does not move vertically at all. When I press the ball it begins to fall and only goes down. No matter how many times I press it the ball continues to drop. Also Steve, what I am trying to get at is. When you press the ball it should rise slightly, it will need subsequent consecutive touches to increase the y position of the ball. So its press the ball and it goes up only so far, but it will begin to drop if you do not continue pressing it.